# Datatable 1.8.0 adding server parameter doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, legacy-code

I am working on a legacy code. Right we are using DataTable 1.8.0. It seems like this version is not supporting aoServerParams. I have also tried

```
"fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {

               aoData.push( { "name": "data1", "value": $("#data1").val() } );
               aoData.push( { "name": "data2", "value": $("#data2").val() } );

               $.getJSON( sSource, aoData, function (json) { 
                  fnCallback(json);
               } )
```

But it doesn't work. Can someone please help.

NOTE: I have to make a POST request.

Comment: What do you mean 'it doesn't work'? Please elaborate.

Comment: Theres params are not send to server.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're mixing up `fnServerParams` and `fnServerData`...  Try this:

```
"fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
        aoData.push( { "name": "data1", "value": $("#data1").val() } );
        aoData.push( { "name": "data2", "value": $("#data2").val() } );
 },
"fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
          $.getJSON( sSource, aoData, function (json) { 
                fnCallback(json);
          });
 },
```